# Playing multiple audio files for through multiple buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

I'm trying to play around with a soundboard app, and I need upwards of 50 buttons (one for each sound that I have) on my view controller. Also, I wanted to make the buttons (and the audio player code) completely programmatically, since it's kind of annoying to keep switching between storyboard and the .h/.m files. Instead of copying and pasting the same button code 50 times, I'm using this for-loop to make the buttons for me:

```
NSUInteger i;
int xCoord=0;
int yCoord=0;
int buttonWidth=100;
int buttonHeight=50;
int buffer = 10;
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    aButton.frame     = CGRectMake(xCoord, yCoord,buttonWidth,buttonHeight );
    [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playAudioMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [scrollView addSubview:aButton];

    yCoord += buttonHeight + buffer;
}
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(700, yCoord)];
```

The playAudioMethod in the selector for the button click event only plays one sound. How can have 50  sounds, each of which corresponds to  a separate button? Sorry if this is a really basic question, I'm still learning objective C. Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's the playAudioMethod:

```
- (void) playButtonSound:(id)inSender
{
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(self.SoundID);
}
```

It basically just plays the SoundID property, which I passed a sound file into through this:

```
   NSURL *buttonURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"medic_taunts01" ofType:@"wav"]];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)buttonURL, &SoundID);
    self.SoundID = SoundID;
```

Comment: Show your playAudioMethod method

Comment: Done, I just added the play audio method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `playAudioMethod` has one argument, which is the `sender`. The `sender` is the button that generated the message.

```
- (void)playAudioMethod:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    switch (button.tag)
    {
           //....
    }
}
```

You can use the button's `tag` property to store a value, for example, you could store an integer that allows you to identify the button in the `playAudioMethod` or you could directly store the name of the audio resource.

Comment: I'll try it, but can I increment tag in the for loop? Maybe using something like: [button tag++] ? Thanks.

Comment: You would rather do something like `button.tag = i`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a soundbank player like http://www.hollance.com/2011/02/soundbankplayer-using-openal-to-play-musical-instruments-in-your-ios-app/